# Conversion failed in datetime column and CASE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[Table].[InsertDate] column is `datetime` and *Allows Nulls*. It used to be varchar and I changed it to datetime.

When I run the following query I get 0 results, which is correct since there are only valid dates and *nulls*:

```
SELECT InsertDate
FROM [Table]
WHERE ISDATE(InsertDate) = 0
  AND InsertDate IS NOT NULL;
```

On the other hand, when I run any of the following queries, I get the error *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        ELSE CAST(InsertDate AS DATETIME)
       END AS InsertDate
FROM [Table];

SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        ELSE InsertDate
       END AS InsertDate
FROM [Table];
```

What's provoking this error? Besides the *null* (which are being processed by the first `CASE`), there's nothing in the column that would generate the error since everything's a valid date.

Thanks.

Comment: The value of the resulting select statement is trying to return a varchar(3) 'ADD' Text in some cases and an actual date time in others.  It can't be both.  Think about the results... so the column has two records one reads 'ADD' and the other reads 1/21/2014 13:30:34.  What's the data type for that column?  It can't be both, and you're explicitly telling the system you want it to be both... thus db errors.  Pick one, do you want a string or do you want a datetime for that column?  let the null be null and change the Displayed value to 'Add' if you must; but don't make the engine do it.

Comment: exactly excellent answer. But it can be both, but he would have to convert date to string...

Comment: But then it woudln't be a datetime anymore.  it'd be a varchar just like the add.  but this `cast(InsertDate as datetime) ` is telling the DB... no no don't use varchar it has to be a date time.  I want this column in the result set called `InsertDate` to be a varchar some of the time and a datetime the other part of the time.  either both are varchar, or don't render the 'add', handle it in the UI if you have to display 'Add' instead of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because SQL defaults to the data type of the referenced column which in this case is Datetime. So when you are trying to insert a non datetime value into it, its throwing an exception. To fix this you would have to convert the datetime value to Varchar so the string 'Add' can be accommodated.

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table
END

CREATE TABLE #Table (ID INT, InsertDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Table(ID, InsertDate)
VALUES(1000, GETDATE()),
     (1001, NULL),
     (1002, GETDATE() - 1),
     (1003, GETDATE() - 2),
     (1004, NULL)
```

**Error:**

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        ELSE InsertDate
       END AS InsertDate
FROM #Table;

/*Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*/
```

**Fix:**

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), InsertDate, 120)
      END AS InsertDate
FROM #Table;
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say in general you are analyzing a null and/or date value , but returning a value of ADD if it's null

You are trying to convert a date field into a char or varchar field and it's telling you you cannot convert this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Data type mismatch error. The column in the result set titled `InsertDate` has both nvarchar and datetime being returned due to the case statement on nulls.

If the system allowed this the results would be

```
ADD               (VARCHAR(3))
1/1/2014 12:37:30 (DATETIME)
```

in the same column.  The database simply can't allow this.

- If you added a where clause to exclude nulls, you'd have no adds, and the system would work.
- If you added a where clause to only include nulls it would work but only have adds.

So how do you fix it?

Either exclude nulls so you have no adds (this seems silly though)

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        ELSE CAST(InsertDate AS DATETIME)
       END AS InsertDate
FROM [Table]
WHERE insertDate IS NOT NULL;
```

or don't do the case in the first place and display Add when the result is null though the UI.

```
SELECT InsertDate
FROM [Table];
```

or treat them as separate columns.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        END AS MissingInsertDate,
       CAST(InsertDate AS DATETIME) AS InsertDate
FROM [Table];
```

or set both values to varchar (though I'm not sure about SQL server syntax)

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN 'Add'
        ELSE CAST(InsertDate AS VARCHAR(50))
       END AS InsertDate
FROM [Table];
```